# Не передаются опции-конфигурации в класс

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, dependency-injection

Я пытаюсь передать опции в класс через конструктор из фала appsettings.json.
Сам файл выглядит вот так:

```
"IDP": {
    "UrlCbr": "https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js",
    "UrlDadata": "https://suggestions.dadata.ru/suggestions/api/4_1/rs/suggest/currency",
    "DadataToken": "94dabe1e8342c21fdad9622be29514d4f0f99bbd8",
    "BotToken": "1549046386:AAHJsdsaMVaCT-8O3D_P8VLxw6EKAr4P9JfSU",
    "BotName": "Hop_hipBot",
    "BotUrl": "https://111295d46c69.ngrok.io/{0}"
}
```

Поэтому я создал класс IDP.cs:

```
public class IDP
{
    public string UrlCbr { get; set; }
    public string UrlDadata { get; set; }
    public  string DadataToken { get; set; }
    public  string BotToken { get; set; }
    public  string BotName { get; set; }
    public  string BotUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Затем в файле Startup.cs я устанавливаю связь:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
    services.Configure<IDP>(Configuration.GetSection("IDP"));
}
```

Эти данные нужны мне в реализации бота:

```
class Bot 
{
    private static TelegramBotClient botClient;
    private static IOptions<IDP> _IDPs;

    public Bot(IOptions<IDP> IDPs)
    {
        _IDPs = IDPs;
    }

    public static async Task<TelegramBotClient> GetBotClientAsync()
    {
        if (botClient != null)
        {
            return botClient;
        }
        botClient = new TelegramBotClient(_IDPs.Value.BotToken);
        var hook = string.Format(_IDPs.Value.BotUrl, @"api/bot");
        await botClient.SetWebhookAsync(hook);
        return botClient;
    }
}
```

Ну и сам бот запускается в Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{                
    Bot.GetBotClientAsync().Wait();
}
```

И при запуске всего приложения поле `_IDPs` в боте оказывается `null`. Почему это так происходит и как мне нужно правильно доставить данные в бота? В других классах всё работает корректно и опции передаются

Comment: Потому что конструктор класса Bot никогда не вызывается, поскольку экземпляр не создается, а значит и DI в нем не учавствует - GetBotClientAsync ведь статический метод. Уберите все слова static, Bot у вас будет фабрикой и инстанцируйте инстанс Bot с помощью DI  и дальше вызывайте GetBotClientAsync

Comment: @vitidev, а как мне обратиться к экземпляру  Bot в методе Configure(), чтобы можно было выставить хуки?

Comment: @vitidev, оформлять как ответ будете? у меня всё получилось